# Code Migration from JDK 1.5 to 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse

What are the steps to be followed for Migration of code from JDK 1.5 to 1.6.

Steps followed :

1. Changed the build Patch of Project as JDK1.6
2. Changed the Compiler as 6
3. Clean and deploy the Project
4. I was getting Compilation error as

```
       *** ERROR ***: Thu Apr 01 05:17:06 PDT 2010    org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: WEB-INF/web.xml
    Stack trace of nested exception:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jst.javaee.web.internal.impl.WebAppDeploymentDescriptorImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.webapplication.WebApp
        at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.War22ImportStrategyImpl.loadDeploymentDescriptor(War22ImportStrategyImpl.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.War22ImportStrategyImpl.importMetaData(War22ImportStrategyImpl.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:145)  



*** ERROR ***: Thu Apr 01 05:17:06 PDT 2010    org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.core.ValidationException: CHKJ3000E: WAR Validation Failed: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: WEB-INF/web.xml
        at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.internal.validation.WarValidator.validateInJob(WarValidator.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.validation.UIWarValidator.validateInJob(UIWarValidator.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.operations.ValidatorJob.run(ValidatorJob.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: This appears to be an error in an eclipse module you are using. I suggest you ask a forum which specificly supports this product. This is not a general Java question, you shouldn't expect to have to do anything to migrate your code.

Comment: I am getting the same message after importing a project into a new instance of Eclipse (so no version changes, etc.). Some googling suggests that cleaning the project often works (didn't for me). I think you are off track with it being a module specific issue, but I think you are probably in the right ballpark with it being something to do with how Eclipse is loading the context. Mind you, in my particular case, I haven't actually figured out how to fix it yet.

Answer (score 15):

In the vast majority of cases, you don't need to do anything at all.  Even recompiling is not strictly necessary.

The few incompatibilities that exist between Java 5.0 and 6.0 are documented in the [JDK 6 Adoption Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/adoptionguide-137484.html).

Answer (score 2):

The code that ran on Java 1.5 will run on 1.6 without any modifications(in you weren't using any internal APIs that is). The public Java api is always forward compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Recompile with new JDK, check warnings (maybe some of classes or methods are deprecated), check if application work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install JDK 6. Update any environmental variables like JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME. Make sure that your IDE points to the new library (most IDEs will do it automatically if restarted after the environmental variables have been updated). Update the project settings to use JDK 6 in your IDE for each project respectively.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your application I suppose here are the list of new features to 1.6 all your code however should work fine.

link [java 1.6 features](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/features.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

I did following and it works fine

```
Changed the build Patch of Project as JDK1.6
Changed the Compiler as 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar error by replacing:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
     version="2.4">
```

with:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
```

When I did this replacement at web.xml, this CHKJ3000E has gone away.